# D2L - User clicks on URL link, how to get User's current course

Tags: desire2learn

I know I can get the courses the user has, but I want to know where the user is at this moment - clicking the link to our external application.  I'm building on the Getting Started example in PHP, from the valence/desire2learn.com website.  We're using d2l for many of the course materials but want to produce some tracking and graphs for students to see.  It would involve getting grade info (which I think I can do), having students enter hours of study (in our application), storing that information and returning a graph comparing course grade and study hours over the course. It would be much better to automatically pick the right course than to have the student pick the right course.

Can it be done (obtain which course the student's in at the time the link is clicked)?  In addition to the annoyance of having to pick which course, it's possible that students are taking more than one course at a time where the teacher is using this tool.

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

If you use LTI v1.0 ([Basic LTI](http://www.imsglobal.org/lti/blti/bltiv1p0/ltiBLTIimgv1p0.html)) to build the link to launch from D2L to your external application, then the LTI context passed to your application will contain a `context_id` property: the value of this property will be the `org unit ID` that identifies the D2L organizational unit for the launch point's context (in this case, the ID of the course offering). Note that until LE v10.2.0 SP1, D2L won't send along the `context_id` for the top org level, but if the user launches an LTI link from a course offering context, you should get the org unit ID for the course offering.

Comment: That is the only place we would want them to use it, from within a course offering's context.  Thanks.